# Difference between none and initial keyword on box-shadow property?

Tags: css, keyword

First of all, I did use Google and SOF Advanced search but I didn't find this question.

Now to my question:

I know that initial sets the shadow to default i.e none.

Then what is the difference between these two keywords WHEN APPLIED TO BOX-SHADOW PROPERTY.

For some properties, none doesn't work so that time it is understood but it doesn't make sense in box-shadow and other such properties.

And I did read w3schools initial keyword page completely and I made this thread after reading that so please don't stick me that. :)

Please help me clear my doubt. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference according to CSS specifications and drafts. However, there is a practical difference, because not all browsers support the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) keyword. Such browsers ignore a declaration with the value `initial`. (If no other style sheet sets the property for an element, then the valus of the property is still its initial value.)

According to the [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/) CR, `initial` “represents the specified value that is designated as the property's initial value”. For the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property, this value is `none`.